# PE file First Thunk and Original First Thunk fields

Tags: windows, portable-executable

I'm learning a bit about `PE files`. The thing I've struggling a bit now it the `First Thunk` and `Original First Thunk` fields. To understand the difference between them I've read this post and that article. To test the problem "live" I've opened said `shell32.dll` or `notepad.exe` files in `PE-bear` and `IDA` BUT that appears the there is NO `import binding` in case of that files in contrast to what the articles say. Here are my question now:

Why there is NO `import binding` in these files?